# Aurelia: can't find name of Route

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to navigate to a route as follows:

add.js:

```
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";
import $ from "jquery";
import {Router} from "aurelia-router";

const baseURI = "/posts";

export class Add {

    constructor() {
        this.router = new Router();
    }

    add() {
        let url = this.router.generate("home");
        this.router.navigate(url);
    }
}
```

app.js:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.map([
        {
            route: ["", "home"],
            moduleId: "./home",
            title: "Home",
            name: "home",
            nav: true
        },
        {
            route: "add",
            moduleId: "./add",
            title: "Add New Post",
            name: "Add",
            nav: true
        }
    ]);
}
```

I am getting this error: `A route with name 'home' could not be found. Check that name: 'home' was specified in the route's config.`

Is it because the route for home is in an array? I tried separating "" and "home" but the error remains.

Comment: try this: `this.router.navigateToRoute('home');`

Comment: I get the same error with `navigateToRoute `

Comment: which line is throwing the error? first or second?  
show the full code of add.js. Perhaps you're not injecting the router properly

Comment: Ok, I will update my question, also after your first suggestion I changed to following code: 

`//let url = this.router.generate("home");
   this.router.navigateToRoute("home");` 

please correct me if this is not what you meant... and got the error on `navigateToRoute()` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inject the router. Doing so, the framework gives to you the same instance that was configured by app.js

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection'; //or aurelia-framework
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";
import $ from "jquery";
import {Router} from "aurelia-router";


@inject(Router)
export class Add {

    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    add() {
        //let url = this.router.generate("home");
        this.router.navigateToRoute("home");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now. I was wondering how the two routers know about each other. One more thing, I am getting a syntax error on `@inject(Router)` line, do I have to add some dependency in jspm, etc?

Comment: no, you don't. Try to `import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';`

Comment: I used that with 'aurelia-framework' in the first place. But that's fixed now,  had to add `"es7.decorators",` in babelOptions in the `config.js`

Comment: Also, your solution works now as expected. Thanks for explanation.